Spring Cloud - Resilience 4J - Circuit Breaker - in AWS AutoScaling Group
I'm really confused here. How does one manage circuit breaker state, when one has multiple instances of a Spring Cloud Gateway app running. Won't each instance have their own circuit breaker state, in memory, which will change on each request that instance receives (depending on how the load balancer sends requests)
How does won't overcome this in an AWS infrastructure? If I use Redis to store state, won't that be queried on every request, for both updating the state in redis, and reading from it? That would place a very large load on Redis, if there are high requests / second, and many instances?
Or am I missing something? How do others overcome this? Is there something in the AWS infrastructure I can use, maybe not Spring Resilience 4J
